# Should we must click the button 2 taps after setting the onclick function for button component in android?

Tags: java, android

When I wanted to add a function to my button component, I found
a bug in my approach, which is that I have to click the button
once more to achieve the desired effect.
In xml I setup the button like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button111"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="button123"
        android:text="@string/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My activity file setup like this:

```
package cn.mr8god.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void button123(View view) {
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.Button111);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a click listener when you click on the button on the first time. Of course you would need to click it once again.

When you click on the button it will call the button123 function, so you don't need a listener.

Just do it like so:

```
public void button123(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for solving my problem. I admit that I made a mistake in understanding the basic concepts. Thanks again! Have a nice day!

Comment: I'm glad I helped! Have a nice day (:

Comment: Actually I had met same problem when I created new function for my mutil thread application. What does it mean?

Comment: @Mr8god Please provide the code. It's probably better to open a new post for that.